# Using a non-interactive service account for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a website that is backed by a database. I requested a SQL Server login with read/write/execute privileges to be created in our Production environment, and our DBA indicated that a non-interactive service account would be preferred.

Are there any potential issues with using a service account in this manner over a SQL Server login?

Comment: You've already mentioned a normal Windows account, a Windows Service account and a SQL Server account. Windows accounts are generally preferable over SQL Server accounts. I suggest you read [this article] (http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/04/21/managed-service-accounts-msa-and-virtual-accounts.aspx) which describes the difference between the various types of accounts, especially the Virtual Accounts used for ASP.NET web sites

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, it is a "best practice" to use a service account (i.e. Windows account) and use SQL logins only for legacy applications that are not able to use Windows accounts (see [Microsoft Recommendation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028697)).
So, only if your website is based on a non Microsoft technology or not hosted by IIS an SQL login might be the better choice.

At my current employer's we've been using non interactive Windows accounts to connect from our ASP.NET applications to SQL server all the time without any problems. It also makes managing and deploying connection strings easier because you don't have to care about securing them.

If you have an ASP.NET application it's good to add the account under which the IIS app pool runs (or a domain group it's in) as a login on the SQL Server.

However an SQL login might also have the practical advantage to be easier to test with: E.g. you can connect to the server using this account with SQL Management Studio to check if the permissions are sufficient.